# What should be Laravel and what should be Vue.js

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

It's been 6 month I use Laravel, and I really love it, and want to keep it.

So now, I'm learning Vue, as Spark will come with Vue, to get some more interactivity.

I display a list a items : Name, adress, FK1_with_relation, FK2_with_relation,etc.

I manage all that data from Eloquent, and it is fine for me.

The only action I would like to perform with AJAX Call is the delete button.

I don't like reloading page each time I need to delete a user.

So I would like to do it with Vue, but I really don't want to generate a special API for that, and I wouldn't like to generate all my table using Vue, I am happy with my eloquent in this case.

I would like to generate the Vuejs as small as posible so that I can delete a row by ajax an remove the row.

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

vue-resource provides the Ajax functionality to delete.